# Memory leak from gtk_label_set_text

Tags: c, gtk

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out a memory leak that's driving me crazy. Through various rounds of troubleshooting, I have narrowed the problem down to one particular section of one particular function which updates a GTK label based on an incoming network message. This function repeats on a timer every 200ms as long as the program is running. If there are no incoming network messages or no incoming messages that match the ones I'm looking for, there is no problem. But when I start sending messages that do match, triggering a gtk_label_set_text call, I start seeing a slow memory leak. As long as matching messages keep coming in, memory drops by exactly 60k every 30-60 seconds. If I stop sending matching messages, the leak immediately stops.

Here is my function:

```
static gboolean get_incoming_message()
{

gchar *buffer = g_malloc(1024);
gssize incoming_size;
GError *err = NULL;

incoming_size = g_socket_receive(listenSocket, (gchar *)buffer, 1024, NULL, &err);


if ( incoming_size > 0 )
{
    gchar *incoming_message = g_strndup ((const gchar *)buffer, incoming_size);

    if ((g_strcmp0(incoming_message, "Show 1 in Progress")==0) || (g_strcmp0(incoming_message, "Show 2 in Progress")==0))
    {

        gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (current_status_message_box), (const gchar *)incoming_message);
    }

    g_free(incoming_message);
    g_free(buffer);
    g_error_free(err);
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    g_free(buffer);
    g_error_free(err);
    return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;

}
```

Again, the leak only occurs when the if statement with the g_strcmp0's in it evaluates to TRUE.

Hoping someone can tell me where I'm going wrong, or if this is actually a problem in GTK is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suffers from some problem:

1. if you don't care of error handling, use `NULL` instead of `err`;
2. if `err` is `NULL`, it must not be `g_error_free`'d: actually it happens to work but don't count on it;
3. if `buffer` is local to your function, just use a local array: it will avoid the `g_free()` on every exit point;
4. `return FALSE` is never reached;

I'd rewrite it this way:

```
static gboolean get_incoming_message()
{   
    gchar buffer[1024];
    gssize incoming_size;

    incoming_size = g_socket_receive(listenSocket, buffer, 1024, NULL, NULL);
    if (incoming_size < 0)
        return FALSE;

    if (incoming_size > 0 &&
        (strncmp(buffer, "Show 1 in Progress", 1024) == 0 ||
         strncmp(buffer, "Show 2 in Progress", 1024) == 0))
        gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(current_status_message_box), buffer);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Other than that, there is no leak in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try later today. But if the leak isn't here, I'm not sure where else it could possibly be, as it seems to go away when I comment out the call to this function. Could it be somewhere in the creation of the GSocket listenSocket? If it was, I would think the leak would still occur when there were incoming messages whether or not I called g_socket_receive...

Comment: Apart from `g_error_free`, your code has no obvious errors. My guess: 1. you don't have leaks (that is, the way you check for leaks is flawed); 2. you're passing non-utf8 text to gtk_label_set_text() (not shown in the above code); 3. the leak is somewhere else.

Comment: Addenum: I just checked your previous code was effectively leaking `incoming_message`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly which part was the problem, but this seems to have fixed it! Thanks so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `gtk_label_set_text()` appears to be fine.

This does not exactly match your description at first glance, but I note that you never free `incoming_message`, so it is going to leak every time a message is received. Perhaps there *are* no messages of nonzero size that don't match your condition?

Comment: I did think of this, but g_free throws an error when I try to free incoming_message, since it's a const gchar. I was under the impression that a const gchar didn't need to be freed. Is this not the case?

I do know that there are nonzero messages that don't match my condition, though, because I am manually sending the messages. But I'm sure it's possible that the leak is occurring each time but only shows itself when a set_text occurs?

Comment: I changed things around to declare incoming_message as a gchar instead of a const and now free it, but I am still seeing exactly the same leak occuring, only when matching messages are received.

Comment: @DrRocket -- making the variable `const` does indeed imply to the compiler that you don't need to free the variable, but the `const` is a lie here, as the string is dynamic memory that does indeed need to be freed. Too bad that this didn't turn out to be the problem. Did you try running with the `gtl_label_set_text()` call commented out? Does that make the leak go away as well?

Comment: I just gave that a try and no, the problem is still there. But now it looks like it's leaking whenever messages are coming in, not just messages that match my conditions. I'm not exactly sure at what point that changed, but it's driving me nuts!